# Javascript ajax django geolocation query

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
<script>
  // window.onload = getLocation();
  function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else {
      x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
  }

  function showPosition(position) {
      console.log(position.coords.latitude);
      console.log(position.coords.longitude);
  }
  // showPosition();
  $(window).on('load', function () {
    getLocation();
    showPosition();
    $.ajax({
       type='POST',
       url = 'abc/xyz',
       data : {
           lat : position.coords.latitude,
           long : position.coords.longitude
          },
        });
  });
</script>
```

I am very new to Jvascript and ajaxand jquery. I am getting this error.
" Uncaught SyntaxError: missing : after property id "
Can someone please guide me as to where the error is?

Comment: Typo. You're using `=` between the properties in the `$.ajax()` call it should be `:` instead.

Comment: Thanks. I got one more. Posititon is undefined, Can you please help me with that?

Comment: `position` is only available within the scope of the `showPosition()` function. You're trying to use it outside of there in the `window.on('load')` event handler, which is not possible.

Comment: any way to send it via ajax? I am trying to post these latitude and longitude to this url to process some data in django backend.

Comment: ANy help will be apprecieated. Stuck in this problem for far too long. This latitude and longitude data I need to send to my django backend.

Comment: Sure, put the `$.ajax()` call inside the `showPosition()` function.